# TexForm for powers of PolyLog gives unexpected form

Tags: output-formatting, latex, output

Although the current `TeXForm` in Mathematica is far from ideal, I wonder if there is any reason for writing power of `PolyLog` as done currently,

```
TeXForm[PolyLog[2,x]^3]
```

which gives

```
\text{Li}_2(x){}^3
```

instead of

```
\text{Li}_2^3(x)
or 
(\text{Li}_2(x))^3
```

For `Log` it is fine

```
TeXForm[Log[x]^3]
```

which gives

```
\log ^3(x)
```

Although the space between `\log` and `^3` is unwanted, it is still okay.
For `PolyLog` why is this not the case?

*13.3.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)*

Comment: "why is this not the case?" does not seem like a very constructive question: if the output is really incorrect or unexpected, then there is no good why. You could perhaps ask for another approach that gives a different output, though. Or a completely different tool to convert MMA output into $\TeX$ perhaps.

Comment: You should look it the other way: Why are trigonometric and logarithmic function in `TeXForm` written with this ambiguous notation $(\sin^3 x$, $\log ^3x)$? All other functions are written with the more appropriate notation of superscript at the end of the arguments.

Comment: @MarcoB            It seemed to me this was a very naive bug. Of course, there is a way around it and for this problem, I am not looking for a solution. It is easy to fix (like manual rules etc.). Just that this is a trivial thing that is not fixed yet seeing that `TeXForm` is not an experimental feature but rather a standard functionality of Mathematica. I think I will send a bug report.

Comment: @Domen          But I thought when writing something in terms of a different language, we have to respect their rules no?

Comment: @BabaYaga, I don't understand your comment. Writing $f^2(x)$ is generally an ambiguous notation because it might mean $f(f(x))$ or $(f(x))^2$. That is why practically all functions, when converted to `TeXForm` in Mathematica, are written with the more precise form: `TeXForm[Beta[x, y]^3]` gives `B(x,y)^3`. It is only the trigonometric (`Sin`, `Cos` ...) and logarithm (as far as I managed to find) that are written with the exponent on the function. This decision was probably made due to common usage of such notation, although this makes it inconsistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @MarcoB and @Domen in the comments, this is a debatable topic and probably off-topic and might not be a bug as I was originally thinking about. From the LaTeX side, we (at least I am) are engineered to see `\ln^3(x)`, `\text{Li}_2^3(x)` etc. However as pointed out by @Domen, this leads to confusion for many.

In any case, if someone wants to get `PolyLog[a,x]^y` to be written as `\text{Li}_a^y(x)` in LaTeX form, one can do a substitution or can change this kind of behavior,

```
Unprotect[Power];
Format[Power[PolyLog[a_,x_],y_], TeXForm] := (Subscript[Li, a]^y)[x];
Protect[Power];
```

which will lead to the desired form:

```
TeXForm[PolyLog[a,x]^y]
```

leading to

```
\text{Li}_a^y(x)
```